# Not able to create to db table, but exception returning typo?

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to make a create function in c#.
Somehow it keeps returning the exception value "Invalid column name 'CategoryEmployeeID'"

My create function :

```
public static void CreateCategory(string createcategoryname, int createcategoryemployeeid)
        {
            Database db = new Database();
            SqlConnection conn = db.connection();
            conn.Open();
            using SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Categories
                                                      (CategoryName, CategoryEmployeeID, CategoryCreatedDate)
                                                      VALUES(@CategoryName, CategoryEmployeeID, getDate())", conn);
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@CategoryName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 32).Value = createcategoryname;
                command.Parameters.Add("@CategoryEmployeeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = createcategoryemployeeid;

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

category constructor :

```
    class Category
    {
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public int CategoryEmployeeID { get; set; }
        public DateTime CategoryCreatedDate { get; set; }

        // Constructor
        public Category(int categoryid, string categoryname, int categoryemployeeid)
        {
            CategoryID = categoryid;
            CategoryName = categoryname;
            CategoryEmployeeID = categoryemployeeid;
            CategoryCreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```

Calling the function from my main :

```
case createCategoryKey:
    Console.Write("Indtast kategorinavn: ");
    string createcategoryname = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Hvilket medarbejder ID har oprettet Kategorien?: ");
    int createcategoryemployeeid = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    try
    {
        Database.CreateCategory(createcategoryname, createcategoryemployeeid);
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + createcategoryname + " Oprettet med success!\n\n");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    break;
```

I understand the error message.. but it shouldnt be the reason.. i have double checked everything, my database table "Categories" has the following setup :

```
CategoryID int
CategoryName nvarchar(32)
CategoryEmployeeID int
CategoryCreatedDate Datetime
```

Name was copied directyly from design view and shouldnt be a typo, i have checked.
(also i know the names are very.. yeah, i am new so i make them as long as descriptive as i can to not get lost)

Comment: This is C#, not BASIC. Please don't use unrelated tags

Comment: You probably forgot the `@` before `CategoryEmployeeID`  in `VALUES(@CategoryName, CategoryEmployeeID, getDate())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is wrong. If you tried to run it with a client tool like SSMS you'd get an error too. In :

```
INSERT INTO Categories (CategoryName, CategoryEmployeeID, CategoryCreatedDate)
VALUES(@CategoryName, CategoryEmployeeID, getDate())
```

The `VALUES` clause references the *field name* `CategoryEmployeeID` instead of a parameter name `@CategoryEmployeeID`. Change this to :

```
VALUES(@CategoryName, @CategoryEmployeeID, getDate())
```